# Structuring Data with Firebase Rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have created an APP where users are able to post `Tasks`. Registered users can see other users tasks, but should not be allowed to edit them, except the user is the poster of that task.

I did not set up firebase rules until now, so everything could get deleted or read. I will try to explain in the best possible way I can, what I try to accomplish.

If I focus on the main Task props in that node it contains 3 essential props:

- status
- posterID
- workerID

Status should not be editable by the poster of the task or anybody else, it should be handled by server-functions. Where posterID should be set by posting a new task and it should also not be editable for anybody. And as for the reading rules, registered users can read all props of a task.

I want to avoid a server-function that accepts task as data and sets it via admin rights to the database, because users will not be able to experience a offline persistance that way.

I have come up with this "not-really-working" solution. I have been stuck by testing if I can edit the status of a task that did not get posted by my userID, because it changes the status. Where it should not be able to do so.

Security rules:

```
   "Tasks" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null", //Users can post tasks
        "$taskID":{
          // Only the owner of the task can edit its props
          ".write": "root.child('Tasks').child('$taskID').child('posterID').val() === auth.uid",
            // But the status is for nobody editable
            "status": {
                ".write": false
            }
        }
   }
```

Code:

```
  updateForeignTask() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("Tasks")
      .child("-LJraTW2KV7BgcSZ8yJ6")
      .update({ status: 2 });
  }

  testingFBRules() {
    const taskID = firebase
      .database()
      .ref("Tasks")
      .push().key;

    var task_to_post = {
      taskID: taskID,
      posterID: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      title: "test",
      desc: "test",
      creationDate: firebase.database().getServerTime(),
      //status: 0,
      workerID: ""
    };

    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("Tasks")
      .child(taskID)
      .set(task_to_post)
      .then(res => {
        var temp;
        alert("res : " + res);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        var temp;
        alert("err: " + error);
      });
  }
```

I have commented out the status prop on testingFBRules() to be able to post a task. I can imagine to trigger a cloud-function for adding the status afterwards with admin-rights. But I am not sure if this is the right way to go.

My question is, how do i setup the firebase-rules to match my requirements. And if it is not possible, how should I restructure my database to make it possible?

Comment: Didn't you ask this (or something very simular) before?

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833803/firebase-rules-tasks?noredirect=1#comment90629154_51833803 @niksn: don't repost the same question please. If you made a mistake or have additional information, click the edit link under your question to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission, once granted, cannot be revoked. Once a user is granted access to a path, they have access to all data under that path too. That means that this:

```
".write": "auth != null", //Users can post tasks
"$taskID":{
  // Only the owner of the task can edit its props
  ".write": "root.child('Tasks').child('$taskID').child('posterID').val() === auth.uid",
    // But the status is for nobody editable
    "status": {
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

The top-level rule here means that any user (`auth != null`) can write all tasks. They can also write `status`, despite the `".write": false`. The other `.write` rule in there also seems meaningless, since it seems to try and tighten access.

You'll typically want to structure your data to match your security requirements. Here that means that I'd model the status in a separate branch from the other task data:

```
Tasks
  $taskId
    posterId: ...
    workerId: ...
Status
  $taskId: 2
```

Now you can secure access for each branch separate, only allowing the user to write to `/Tasks` (since `/Status` is managed by your server).